# How to autoclick button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I want to clicked button automaticly after I restarted the activity. Here is my code:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Yes") {dialogInterface, i ->
                    finish()
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                    startActivity(getIntent())
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                    // autoclick buton
}
```

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.performClick();
    }
}, 5000);
```

I tried this by converting to Kotlin but couldnt fix it.

Comment: What is `button1` here ? if u want to call a block of code then just move that code to a method and call that method in both places ..

Comment: Syntax error just 'button' I mean. It didn't work to moving in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a seprate function on the click of button and should call that function again on restarting the activity

Comment: 'fun click(){
        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            it.performClick()
        }
    }
 '  
then i called the click function like this but it just didn't work
'alert.setPositiveButton("Yes") {dialogInterface, i ->
                    finish()
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                    startActivity(getIntent())
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                    click()

                }
'

Comment: i think you should try moving the finish method after the click

Comment: i found another way thanks for your help